# Clicking a href selects hidden radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to implement a plans page. In this page a user can only select one plan obviously. So I have a form that has radio buttons representing each plan. But Radio buttons are ugly right!? So I'm trying to hide them behind a regular a href styled nicely. Is it possible to have an a href actually select a radio button on it's behalf? Here is my code:

## HTML:

```
  <label class="plans__trial__actions">
    <input type="radio" id="trial" name="slug" value="trial" />
    <a href="#" class="button" id="free">Select</a>
  </label>
```

So for for the radio button I'm use `display: none;` to hide the radio button then trying to select that button when a user clicks the a href that below the radio button. How can I achieve this?

Comment: *"But Radio buttons are ugly right!?"* - Nope.

Comment: I'm no front end guy, hence the question I'm asking. But I've never seen a pretty radio button. But I'm sure they are out there.

Comment: Yeah, my comment wasn't very constructive. Anyway, can you please [edit] your question to show the actual HTML of the radio button rather than the server-side `<%= %>` code - makes it easier for people to include demos in their answer if they can just copy your HTML. Note also that given a click on a label will select its associated radio button you could possibly just style the labels rather than adding in anchors.

Comment: Updated @nnnnnn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to all checkbox example check. Looking at the structure of your html, if the input sibling is next to the anchor tag you can add a click event to all anchor.when the event fires, the anchor will check their sibling-checkbox.

**Snippet below without the checkbox hidden**

```js
all_anchor=document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for(var x=0;x<all_anchor.length;++x){
all_anchor[x].addEventListener("click",function(){
this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;
})
}
```

```css
a{
padding:30px;
background:red;
border:solid red;
border-radius:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<label class="plans__trial__actions">
    <input type="radio" id="trial" name="slug1" value="trial" class="check"/>
    <a href="#" class="button" id="free">Select</a>
  </label>
<label class="plans__trial__actions">
    <input type="radio" id="trial" name="slug2" value="trial" class="check"/>
    <a href="#" class="button" id="free">Select</a>
  </label>
<label class="plans__trial__actions">
    <input type="radio" id="trial" name="slug3" value="trial" class="check"/>
    <a href="#" class="button" id="free">Select</a>
  </label>
```

**Snippet below where all input box are hidden but checked by the anchor tag**

```js
all_anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var x = 0; x < all_anchor.length; ++x) {
  all_anchor[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.previousElementSibling.checked = true;
    console.log("input sibling is checked")
  })
}
```

```css
a {
  padding: 30px;
  background: red;
  border: solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.check {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="plans__trial__actions">
    <input type="radio" id="trial" name="slug1" value="trial" class="check"/>
    <a href="#" class="button" id="free">Select</a>
  </label>
<label class="plans__trial__actions">
    <input type="radio" id="trial" name="slug2" value="trial" class="check"/>
    <a href="#" class="button" id="free">Select</a>
  </label>
<label class="plans__trial__actions">
    <input type="radio" id="trial" name="slug3" value="trial" class="check"/>
    <a href="#" class="button" id="free">Select</a>
  </label>
```